# Keycloak-connect check if *-token is valid and is in session

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, mqtt, keycloak

I'm setting up a server with `expressjs` and `keycloak-nodejs-connect`, they are linked between them over common Storage for sessions. This works fine, ie, the flow with keycloak authentication its ok.

Now, I'm setting up a `MQTT broker (Aedes)` over server from expressjs. The unique authentication method in MQTT is username/password, then, I'm thinking about send the "token" (1) from webclient in the mqtt client connection flow in order to check on backend with keycloak-connect-nodejs if this token is valid.

I'm searching for some days and I cannot found a solution for this. How can i do? ie, verify the username received in the connection process on mqtt broker aginst keycloak over keycloak-connect-nodejs.

Or ... ¿are there other way to "link" mqtt authentication with my keycloak-session or express-session?

Thank you in advance.

(1) Which token should I use? From client I with keycloak.js I have the following token availables: `idToken`, `token`, `subject`, `sessionId`

**Edit/Update with a solution**

Several days later from starting my investigation, I have found the solution, my problem was that I'm trying authenticate into introspection endpoint with the accessToken, and I should do it with basic auth: client_name and client_secret. I have found the solution here: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-April/005869.html